# Cannot get timeout to work due to possible errors in callback structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the following code to call a server process two time in a single button press operation.  My requirements state that I need to try two times, and update the user that I a retrying.  If either try works then I present a success message, if both fail then I tell them to 'Try again'.

As coded, the following code **works**. The only problem is that I would like each of the messages to appear for one second so that they can be read.

I have tried every combination of setTimeout(1000) and delay(1000) and it either had no effect, or hung at that point.  I suspect that there is a logic flaw with my callback structure.  Can someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong?

```
$(".infoMessage").text("Starting Open Process...");
var deferred = openATMRPC.openATMFirst();
deferred.addCallback(function(result){

    if (result == "false") {
      $(".infoMessage").text("Attempting Second try...");
      var insideDeferred = openATMRPC.openATMSecond();
       insideDeferred.addCallback(function(result) {
       if (result == "false") {
           $(".infoMessage").text("Try Again Later");
       } else {
            $(".infoMessage").text("Success 2");
        }
    })
  } else if(result == "true"){
      $(".infoMessage").text("Success 1");
    }
  }
)
```

Note:  My server process returns a string of "true" or "false" whether it was successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern , utilizing [jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".infoMessage").text("Starting Open Process...");
    // included `trueFalse` argument , here , to display flow of results
    // not certain if `openATMRPC.openATMFirst()` , 
    // `openATMRPC.openATMSecond()` returns a `promise` object ?
    // utilized same function applied to both `deferred` and `insideDeferred` 
    var deferred = function(trueFalse) {
        // return value from response as `deferred.promise`
        // within `setTimeout` , after `1000` ms (one second)
        return new $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.post("/echo/html/", {
                html: trueFalse
            })
        // `deferred.always` utilized here ,
        // to catch either `success` or `fail` ,
        // not certain about `error` (`fail`) callbacks ?
            .always(function (data) {
                dfd.resolve(data)
            })
        }, 1000);
        // return `deferred.promise()` , 
        // e.g., "true" , or "false"
        return dfd.promise()
    })
    };
    // `deferred()` function called with `"false"` argument
    deferred("false").done(function (result) {
        if (result == "false") {
            $(".infoMessage").text("Attempting Second try...");
            // `insideDeferred` = `deferred()` called with `"true"` argument 
            var insideDeferred = deferred("true");
            insideDeferred.done(function (result) {
                if (result == "false") {
                    $(".infoMessage").text("Try Again Later");
                } else {
                    $(".infoMessage").text("Success 2");
                }
            })
        } else if (result == "true") {
            $(".infoMessage").text("Success 1");
        }
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/vpy207t9/

```js
$(function () {
    $(".infoMessage").text("Starting Open Process...");
    var deferred = function(trueFalse) {
        return new $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
        setTimeout(function () {
                dfd.resolve(trueFalse)
        }, 1000);
        return dfd.promise()
    })
    };
    deferred("false").done(function (result) {
        if (result == "false") {
            $(".infoMessage").text("Attempting Second try...");
            var insideDeferred = deferred("true");
            insideDeferred.done(function (result) {
                if (result == "false") {
                    $(".infoMessage").text("Try Again Later");
                } else {
                    $(".infoMessage").text("Success 2");
                }
            })
        } else if (result == "true") {
            $(".infoMessage").text("Success 1");
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infoMessage"></div>
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  Let me take some time to dissect and see if I can get it to work in my specific environment.  Thank you!